# Why does matplotlib.pyplot.scatter() not support 'markeredgewidth' or 'mew' keywords?

Tags: python, matplotlib

It appears for each function you have to customize the plots a little different. Why is it implemented that way? Is it just by chance, or is it not possible to implement a uniform set of keywords that works for most functions?

e.g. pyplot.scatter() uses 'c' while plt.plot() uses 'color'.

I am puzzled each time when I have to google how to do these things and I would like to understand the reasons, if there are some.

Comment: I believe `scatter` uses `linewidth`/`lw`  for the edge colour. *Why* they did this is probably less easy to answer.